# how to create password to folder using c#

Tags: c#, locking, directory

how to create password to windows folder using c#

shall I set password to folders when it is created.

Comment: It will be very hard to come up with a decent answer to this. Please rephrase your question and include more detail as to what your intentions are.

Answer (score 4):

You can't set a password on a folder in either FAT32 or NTFS, however you can set up so that only certain user accounts can access it using the [DirectorySecurity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.directorysecurity.aspx) class. There's some sample code in that link.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this cannot be done using C#. The only real reliable way of achieving something like this is to write a kernal-mode [File System Filter Driver](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/driver/filterdrv/default.mspx). If you install the WDK there is an example called [minispy Minifilter Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff549778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which would be a good starting point for you.