# Set password for a folder

Tags: c#, passwords, directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to create password to folder using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428402/how-to-create-password-to-folder-using-c)

Hi, I want to set password for a folder programmaticaly.how can i do that?
If admin user set a password for a folder can other users access to it with that password?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056295/password-protection-for-shared-folder